# xunit Assert.ThrowsAsync() does not work properly?

Tags: .net, unit-testing, asynchronous, xunit.net

So I have a test like the following:

```
[Fact]
public void Test1()
{
    Assert.ThrowsAsync<ArgumentNullException>(() => MethodThatThrows());
}

private async Task MethodThatThrows()
{
    await Task.Delay(100);
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

To my surprise, Test1 passes successfully. To make it fail I have to write like this:

```
Assert.Throws<ArgumentNullException>(() => MethodThatThrows().Wait());
```

What is the purpose of `ThrowsAsync()`, if it does not work in the scenario above?

Answer (score 166, accepted):

You're supposed to `await` the result (see [xunit's acceptance tests](https://github.com/xunit/xunit/blob/c54cc52ffb275c81afed022521870193bbca6c39/test/test.xunit.assert/Asserts/ExceptionAssertsTests.cs#L490) for examples and alternate forms).

```
[Fact]
async void Test1()
{
    await Assert.ThrowsAsync<ArgumentNullException>(() => MethodThatThrows());
}
```

In this specific degenerate case, you could just `return` the `Task` that `Assert.ThrowsAsync` yields without using `await`; but in that case, the key thing is to yield the `Task` back to the xUnit framework, i.e.

```
[Fact]
Task Test1() =>
    Assert.ThrowsAsync<ArgumentNullException>(MethodThatThrows);
```

Comment: Thank you! I can never remember that the `await` goes at the front of the line!

Answer (score 43):

Just in case anyone wants to separate Act and Assert part, below code can be used:

```
//Act
Task result() => systemUnderTest.AsyncMethodThatThrows();

//Assert
await Assert.ThrowsAsync<Exception>(result);
```

Comment: I had to remove the "await" in my case. Thanks!

Comment: @neoscribe, a better way imo, is to make it async.